# Databricks subprocess vs os.system

Tags: subprocess, sh, databricks, azure-databricks, tar

I have the following shell command that I'm trying to run in databricks:

```
find /dbfs/mnt/data/ -name somename.tar.tar -exec tar -xvzf {} -C /dbfs/mnt/raw/data \;
```

When I run it as a shell command or using os.system as shown below in a databricks notebook it works and extracts the files.
Shell:

```
%sh    
find /dbfs/mnt/data/ -name somename.tar.tar -exec tar -xvzf {} -C /dbfs/mnt/raw/data \;
```

python:

```
cmd = ['find', '/dbfs/mnt/data/', '-name', 'somename.tar.tar', '-exec', 'tar', '-xvzf', '{}', '-C', '/dbfs/mnt/raw/data', '\\;']
cmd_join = " ".join(cmd)
os.system(cmd_join)
```

But running it as a subprocess does not seem to do anything even if the cell runs successfully.

```
subprocess.run(cmd)
```

Why is this the case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you run `subprocess` with a list, you need to peel off any quotes or escapes which were necessary when you ran the command with a shell between you and the command line.

Specifically, the backslash before the `;` is necessary when you have a shell because the semicolon character by itself is a statement terminator in the shell. But now you don't have a shell; so, take it out.

```
cmd = [
    'find', '/dbfs/mnt/data/', '-name', 'somename.tar.tar',
    '-exec', 'tar', '-xvzf', '{}', '-C', '/dbfs/mnt/raw/data', ';']
```

Probably also add `check=True` to your command;

```
s = subprocess.run(cmd, check=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

Check the error you are getting with below code.

```
import subprocess
s = subprocess.run(cmd,capture_output=True)
print("Error "+s.stderr.decode())
print("Output "+s.stdout.decode())
```

When i tried your command i got the below error.

[image]

So, terminate the `exec` command by `;` .

code :

```
import subprocess

cmd = ['find', '/dbfs/FileStore/', '-name', 'sample.tar.tar', '-exec', 'tar', '-xvf', '{}', '-C', '/dbfs/mnt/raw/data', ';']
s = subprocess.run(cmd,capture_output=True)
print("Error "+s.stderr.decode())
print("Output "+s.stdout.decode())
```

Output:

[image]

Or

you can run command by passing `cmd` as single string and giving `shell` argument as `True`.

code:

```
cmd = ['find', '/dbfs/FileStore/', '-name', 'sample.tar.tar', '-exec', 'tar', '-xvf', '{}', '-C', '/dbfs/mnt/raw/data', '\\;']
cmd_join = " ".join(cmd)
s = subprocess.run(cmd_join,shell=True,capture_output=True)
print("Error "+s.stderr.decode())
print("Output "+s.stdout.decode())
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: You really want to avoid running things with `shell=True` if you can. Also, blindly concatenating things with spaces between them is wrong for many nontrivial scripts. See also  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3172470/actual-meaning-of-shell-true-in-subprocess

Comment: @tripleee I have already given the solution in my first approach and i given second approach because, if user wants to run with `\\;` on single string command.